# Trouble writing a peer to peer chat System

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

This is the Problem Statement i Was Given :

Design a protocol where a server is responsible to match up two chatt clients. The server listens on a TCP port for upcoming connections.
If no client is already connected to the server to be paired, the server accepts the connecting client, and makes it wait for another client. To do that, it sends a message to the connecting client to wait. When recieving this command the client constructs another Server Socket instance to listen on a port   . The client then sends a mesagge to the server that contains the port number in which the newly created server listens on. 
When another client, C2, seeks a connection with the server while C1 is waiting, the server informs C2 the existence of C1 by sending a message “PEER_LOC $h:$p” to C2, where $h is the host name (or IP address) of C1 and $p is the port number on which C1 is waiting. After C2 receives this message, it seeks a connection to C1 using the obtained information.Clients get the messages from users. The two clients then exchange messages until either party sends an end of stream” (Ctrl-D in Linux). Their conservation is then terminated.Sophisticated methods may employ multiple threads, timeouts, etc., and is not required in this problem.

My issues is connecting two clients to my Server. I run my server program and then two other clients classes that are duplicated of each other only with different names. I can connect to one of them only the other one just seems to wait forever.

Theses are my classes I run.

The server:

```
package chatserver2;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
   // import all the class that you will need for functionailty

// extends jframe to develop gui's in java
public class Server {

    private static ObjectOutputStream output; // stream data out
    private static ObjectInputStream input; // stream data in
    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static Socket connection; // socket means set up connetion between 2 computers

    private static int n;

//Constructor
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Server obj = new Server();
        obj.RunServer();

        try {
            while (true) {

                Handler obj2 = new Handler();

                obj2.start();
                System.out.println("Accepted connection from "
                        + connection.getInetAddress() + " at port "
                        + connection.getPort());

                n++;
                System.out.println("Count " + n);
            }
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }

    }

    public Server() {

    }

// run the server after gui created
    public void RunServer() {

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(6789); // 1st number is port number where the application is located on the server, 2nd number is the amount of people aloud to connect
            while (true) {

                try {
                    waitForConnection(); // wait for a connection between 2 computers 
                    setupStreams();  // set up a stream connection between 2 computers to communicate
                    whileChatting();  // send message to each other
                    // connect with someone and have a conversation
                } catch (EOFException eofException) {

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {

            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//Wait for a connection then display connection information
    private void waitForConnection() {

        try {
            connection = server.accept();
        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    // stream function to send and recive data

    private void setupStreams() throws IOException {

        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); // set up pathway to send data out
        output.flush(); // move data away from your machine
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // set up pathway to allow data in

    }

// this code while run during chat conversions
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException {

        String message = "WAIT ";
        sendMessage(message);

        do {

            try {

                message = (String) input.readObject(); // stores input object message in a string variable

                System.out.println("Message from Client " + message);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException classnotfoundException) {

            }
        } while (!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));// if user types end program stops

    }

    private void closeChat() {

        try {

            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

// send message to the client
    private void sendMessage(String message) {

        try {

            output.writeObject(message);
            output.flush();

            System.out.println("Message to client " + message);

        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

        }

    }

    public static class Handler extends Thread {

        private Socket connection;

        public Handler() {

            String message = "WAIT";

        }

        public void run() {

            System.out.println("Connect" + Server.connection);
            while (true) {

                try {
                    waitForConnection();
                    setupStreams();
                    whileChatting();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }

        }

        private void waitForConnection() {

            System.out.println("server" + server);
            try {
                connection = server.accept();
            } catch (IOException ioexception) {

                ioexception.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Connection" + connection);

        }

        private void setupStreams() throws IOException {

            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); // set up pathway to send data out
            output.flush(); // move data away from your machine
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // set up pathway to allow data in

        }

        private void whileChatting() throws IOException {

            String message = " You are now connected ";
            sendMessage(message);

            do {

                try {

                    message = (String) input.readObject();

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException classnotfoundException) {

                }
            } while (!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));

        }

        private void closeChat() {

            try {

                output.close();
                input.close();
                connection.close();

            } catch (IOException ioexception) {

                ioexception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        static private void sendMessage(String message) {

            try {

                output.writeObject(message);
                output.flush();

            } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            }

        }

    }
}
```

The and one  duplicated client classes  C1, or C2:

```
package chatserver2;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
   // import all the class that you will need for functionailty

// extends jframe to develop gui's in java
public class Client1 extends JFrame {

    private JTextField userInput; // 
    private JTextArea theChatWindow; //
    private ObjectOutputStream output; // stream data out
    private ObjectInputStream input; // stream data in

    private Socket connection; // socket means set up connetion between 2 computers

//Constructor
    public Client1() {

    }

// run the server after gui created
    public void RunClient() {

        try {
            connection = new Socket("localhost", 6789);// 1st number is port number where the application is located on the server, 2nd number is the amount of people aloud to connect
            while (true) {

                try {
                    // wait for a connection between 2 computers 
                    setupStreams();  // set up a stream connection between 2 computers to communicate
                    whileChatting();  // send message to each other
                    // connect with someone and have a conversation
                } catch (EOFException eofException) {

                } finally {

                    closeChat();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {

            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//Wait for a connection then display connection information
    // stream function to send and recive data
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException {

        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); // set up pathway to send data out
        output.flush(); // move data away from your machine
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // set up pathway to allow data in

    }

// this code while run during chat conversions
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException {

        String message = "";

        do {
            // have conversion while the client does not type end
            try {

                message = (String) input.readObject(); // stores input object message in a string variable
                System.out.println("message " + message);
                if (message.equals("WAIT")) {
                    ServerSocket server2 = new ServerSocket(5000);
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                    message = "5000";
                    sendMessage(message);

                }
                System.out.println("From server " + message);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException classnotfoundException) {

            }
        } while (!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));// if user types end program stops

    }

    private void closeChat() {

        try {

            output.close(); // close output stream
            input.close(); // close input stream
            connection.close(); // close the main socket connection

        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

// send message to the client
    private void sendMessage(String message) {

        try {

            output.writeObject(" - " + message);
            output.flush(); // send all data out

        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            theChatWindow.append("\n ERROR: Message cant send");
        }

    }

//
//
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client1 obj = new Client1();
        obj.RunClient();
    }

}
```

I can connect to the first Client i run the second client waits for ever. 
Any Suggestions or comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're blocking server cycle. You should start new thread for each connection from client. I would separate `waitForConnection()` from downstream code in server's loop in `RunServer` method. So your while loop there should look like:

```
public static void RunClient() {
    ...
        while (true) {
            try {
                final Server srv = waitForConnection(); // wait for a connection between 2 computers 
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            srv.setupStreams();  // set up a stream connection between 2 computers to communicate
                            srv.whileChatting();  // send message to each other
                            // connect with someone and have a conversation
                        } catch (EOFException ex) {
                            // ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            } catch (EOFException eofException) {

            }
        }
```

In this case you have to make Server instance for each client and your server declaration should contain non-static props related to client like:

```
public class Server {
    private ObjectOutputStream output; // stream data out
    private ObjectInputStream input; // stream data in
    private static ServerSocket server;
    private Socket connection; // socket means set up connetion between 2 computers
...
```

And Server creation should happen inside `waitForConnection()` like:

```
private static Server waitForConnection() {
    try {
        Socket connection = server.accept();
        return new Server(connection);
    } catch (IOException ioexception) {
        ioexception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It's not the only way to do it. You may preserve Server class for being responsible for running main cycle in the same instance. But in this case I would create some additional class handling properties related to connection from particular client (connection, input, output).

Comment: Changing the static members breaks my the code.  I reference the connection variable in my main method.

Comment: Your first suggestion is that in the client or server RunClient is in the client class?

Comment: Do i have to change my nested inner class Handler in any way I very new is this the right approach ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you think to bring it down to the essence, or it might not, I don't know really.

i

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server implements Runnable{

    private final ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientBuffer;

    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                if(clientBuffer != null) {
                    //Accept new connection and echo ip and port, as the assignment tells you to, then set clientBuffer to null and start the process again. Change Client accordingly.
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What would the main class look like to i have to change that much . In my server class I have a inner class is that necessary?